# Android Traffic Stats Results in Extraordinarily Large Value

Tags: java, android, networking, wifi, traffic-measurement

I'm attempting to monitor the amount of WiFi usage consumed by a device using TrafficStats however when I attempt to do so I result in an extraordinarily large value. Even after performing a factory reset on the device I'm getting a VERY large value for the amount of data used (411970 MB of data usage within one minuteof resetting the device does not seem accurate)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

SOURCE:

```
public class WifiMonitor extends Activity {

    Button sendButton;

    EditText msgTextField;

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView infoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.traffic_info);
        String info = "";

        info += ("\tWifi Data Usage: " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() / 1000000 + " MB");

        infoView.setText(info);

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("3055555555", null, info, null, null);   

        if (info.length() > 0) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://wifiusage.atwebpages.com/receiver.php");
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", info));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(WifiMonitor.this, Alarm.class);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(WifiMonitor.this, 0,
                myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 30 * 1000, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Comment: There's this thing called [Order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) ... ;)

Comment: Please excuse my dear android slipup ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the number of bytes, too

```
TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() / 1000000
```

So you are writting two numbers together, without spaces or any separators in between (first number of bytes, then number of MB).

Use brackets to aggrupate the operations

```
(TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()) / 1000000
```

Comment: Quick question - if I need to subtract the 3g/4g data usage from the total usage (to determine the specific wifi usage) I think I would use the following method - but it's resulting in an extraordinarily large value again (can you assist? last question - I promise!) 

info += ("\tWifi Data Usage: " + ((TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()) - ((TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000  + " MB"));

Comment: Again you are not grouping the first term of the values. Remove unneded brackets (first one for example) and check where each bracket is closed (most IDEs show it when you click in the opening one).

Answer (score 1):

**These are bytes!**
For correct result you must divide bytes like this:

- bytes / 1024 to get KB
- bytes / (1024 * 1024) to get MB
- bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) to get GB

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but those are KiB, MiB and GiB respectively.